# Was Chiyo's real father ever shown?

Tags: azumanga-daioh

In Azumanga Daioh, Osaka sometimes dreams about Chiyo's father. In her dreams, he's a strange being voiced by Wakamoto Norio, capable of levitation and speaking in English, yet he claims to be a cat.

[image]

Is Chiyo's real father ever shown, or is this strange "cat" the only reference to him in the series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Her father was never really shown. However, they are at least alive, as Chiyo talks to them when she comes home once.

Answer (score 2):

According [here](http://azumanga.wikia.com/wiki/Chiyo-chichi),

> The whereabouts and identity of Chiyo's real father, (and mother for that matter) are unknown. (It shown in the anime that they are alive, and in the manga Chiyo is seen waking her parents up at her house, but they are never seen or heard)