# What kind of creature is Chiyo-chichi?

Tags: azumanga-daioh

Chiyo-chichi (Chiyo-Dad, or "Father Cat" in the dub) is a strange creature that appears in  Osaka and Sakaki's dreams. He says he's not a real cat before he tells Sakaki to "find a real cat."

What kind of creature is he? Where did the author get the idea of creating him?

He's the strange creature in the middle -- he doesn't like tomatoes because they are red :

[image: He hates red things]

Comment: Can you clarify for the people who haven't seen the show (like me) which one is Chiyo-chichi in the picture?

Comment: He's the strange one in the middle.

Comment: Related, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/was-chiyos-real-father-ever-shown/3495#3495.

Comment: @xjshiya Not really. I'm asking about the actually character voiced by Wakamoto Norio, not Chiyo's actual father.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Azumanga Daioh wiki](http://azumanga.wikia.com/wiki/Chiyo-chichi) ([revision permalink](http://azumanga.wikia.com/wiki/Chiyo-chichi?oldid=5400)),

> Chiyo-chichi ("Chiyo-Dad" 「ちよ父」"Chiyo-chichi"), is a strange yellow cat like creature...

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Azumanga_Daioh_characters#Chiyo-Father) ([revision permalink](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Azumanga_Daioh_characters&oldid=611997598)),

> "Chiyo-Father" (「ちよ父」 "Chiyo-chichi") is a strange-looking and even stranger-acting cat-like creature...

According to [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/AzumangaDaioh?from=Main.AzumangaDaioh), Chiyo's father is one example of a [Mega Neko](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MegaNeko) or is a [Mind Screw](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MindScrew) element that was added to the anime by the author to keep the audience guessing. About who or what he really is, only [Azuma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiyohiko_Azuma) knows.

Comment: I'm asking what (type of creature) he is, not the whereabouts of Chiyo's parents.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for that. I'll edit my answer. :P